# Python Classes and Replace Function?

Tags: python

```
randomState = collections.namedtuple('randomState', ['player', 'score'])
```

Let's say I have a namedtuple that contains player/score and if I were to replace any of those functions, I would do:

```
def random(state):
    return state._replace(score='123')
```

How do I create a class that has a function that basically resembles a namedtuple, and is able to replace either player/score manually?

```
class Random:
    def abc(self, score):
        if self.score == '123':
            ###had it were a namedtuple, I would use the replace function here, but classes don't allow me to do that so how would I replace 'score' manually?
```

I'm not sure if I'm making sense here, but if anyone understands my problem I'd much appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you need a function which, depending on score's value assigns some new value to it.
Is it what you are looking for?

```
# recommended to use object as ancestor
class randomState(object):
    def __init__(self, player, score):
        self.player = player
        self.score = score

    def random(self, opt_arg1, opt_arg2):
        # you may want to customize what you compare score to
        if self.score == opt_arg1:
            # you may also want to customize what it replaces score with
            self.score = opt_arg2
```

Example:

```
my_state = randomState('David', '100')
new_state = my_state.random('100', '200')
```

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much. I can't believe i didn't think of this.